# JMS Message Selector doesn't work in Multi-Server Environment

Tags: java, spring, jms, hornetq, spring-jms

I've implemented spring jms with HornetQ. It works perfectly If Its one app-server to HornetQ. However If two app servers are accessing the HornetQ. I doesn't work. Inorder to identify different server I've introduced clientId, still it doesn't work. Here is my flow.

1. Prepare message for send with clientId(unique serverId which is sending message) with correlation Id and send it to HorentQ with Quename 'Q1' with ProducerCallback and wait for the response.

   ```
   request.setStringProperty("clientId", clientId);
   request.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
   ```
2. In the Consumder side I've `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which will be listening for the queue Q1. Once the message is received I process it and set correlaionId and clientId back in the response object and send it to another Q 'Q2'

   ```
   final String clientId = request.getStringProperty("clientId");
   final String correlationId = request.getJMSCorrelationID();


   response.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
   response.setStringProperty("clientId", clientId);
   ```
3. In Sender Side I've another `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which will be listening for the Q2. with message selector to select message based on the clientId.

   ```
   <bean id="jmsContatiner"
       class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
       <property name="messageSelector" value="clientId='server1'" />
       <property name="concurrency" value="1" />
       <property name="messageListener" ref="responseListener" />
       <property name="destinationName" value="Q2" />
       <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
   </bean>
   ```

---

The code works fine when one server is envolved. But second server's message is never received by the listener in that server, that listens to Q2(as I see in JConsole of HornetQ). Here is what happens.

Server1 sends message to Q1 and consumer receives message processes it and puts on Q2 and Server1 receives the message from Q1 by selecting message on clientId server1. However when Server2 sends the message to Q1 and consumer receives message processes it and puts on to Q2.

However Server2 listener is not able to select message based on clientId server2. When I restart the server and start of my test with server2, notw server2 works but server1 doesn't pick up the message.

Comment: Isn't value should be quoted? I.e. `<property name="messageSelector" value="clientId='server1'" />`

Comment: Sorry it was copy mistake, values is within quotes. and in log I can see clientId is server1 or server2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue added cache level to CACHE_CONNECTION and client Id. It started working perfectly.

```
<bean id="jmsContatiner"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="messageSelector" value="clientId='server1'" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="1" />
    <property name="clientId" value="server1" />
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="1" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="responseListener" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="Q2" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```